# how do I save and retrieve date in Timestamp format in couchbase databse using springboot

Tags: date, timestamp, save, couchbase

I want to save date in Timestamp format in couchbase database using spring boot application.
I have tried this but getting exception while retrieving date from couchbase.
Here is my code:
POJO:

```
public class Request {
    private Timestamp createDate;
    private Timestamp updateDate;
}
```

Taken in POJO.

```
saving into db:
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
urxRequest.setCreateDate(timestamp);
```

here it is saving date as a long so while retrieving I am getting cast exception.. can not cast from long to Date..

Please help me for this.